# Can you run a browser inside VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can run VS Code on a web browser? But can you run a web browser in VS Code. Suppose you two two editor panels in one VS Code window, but one of the panels is Chrome or Edge.

Comment: Why do you need this? Are you making a web app? Because there are extensions like Live Preview for that sort of use-case. But if this is just so you don't want to alt-tab to a browser, then I would say your question is off-topic because it's both a recommendation question and not strictly about programming.

Comment: It's not a recommendation, I'm asking if this feature exists. I understand your concern but a question doesn't have to be strictly about programming for it to be on this site, see my previous post "How to install a vscode extension for all profiles" which had no objections.

It's a niche case perhaps, but I do fullscreen split view on my mac with vs code on one side and a web browser on another. Mac doesn't allow you to alt-tab to another in split view like windows does.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is built using Electron, which is built using Chromium (the same browser that Chrome and Edge are based on). I'm not aware of a way to embed an arbitrary web browser inside VS Code (or an Electron app or something built on top of Chromium), but [Electron has a `<webview>` tag](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag) based on [Chromium's `webview` feature](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webviewTag/), and [VS Code has a `WebView` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WebviewPanel), which you can create `WebViews` with using `createWebviewPanel`. I assume that feature creates a webview using Chromium-based features.